# How can I use Rolle's theorem to show that $0\leq \sqrt{10^{4}+1} - 100 \leq 5.10^{-3}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a hard time to understand how to do it.

I think what blocks me, is that the Rolle's theorem is usually applied to functions, yet here there aren't any. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explicit proof.

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$$ with $a=10^4$ and $b=10^4+1$

Roll's theorem is: there exist $c \in (a,b) $ such that $f'(c)=\frac {f(b)-f(a)}
{b-a}$

$$\sqrt{10^4+1}-100=\frac{\sqrt{10^4+1}-\sqrt{10^4}}{10^4+1-10^4}=f'(c)$$ where $c \in (10^4, 10^4+1)$

$$f'(c)=0.5c^{-0.5}\le0.5\times0.01 $$

and of course,

$$f'(c) \ge 0$$

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to use a consequence of Rolle's theorem: the mean value theorem, which states that for $ f $ continuous in $ [a, b] $ and differentiable in $ (a, b) $, we have

$$ f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} $$

for some $ c \in (a, b) $. To prove the mean value theorem, define a function $ g(x) = f(x) - rx $ and choose $ r $ such that $ g(a) = g(b) $, and apply Rolle's theorem on $ g $.

Now, your example is a simple application of the mean value theorem for $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

First, it's not *Rolle's theorem* which is applied, but its direct consequence, the *Mean value theorem*, from which one can deduce inequalities.

Second, the function to consider is plainly $\sqrt x$.